# History of downloaded iBookstore samples?

Tags: ios, icloud, books

For some reason—presumably a sync by my iPhone that overwrote my iPad’s more recently downloaded library—the majority of my iBooks were deleted.

The books I purchased can easily be restored, but I had downloaded a *bunch* of samples to, well, sample, before I bought the books.

Shy of using the restore feature, which will probably wreak its own havoc the way my iPhone did, when I synchronized iCloud through it, is there any log or history of the samples I have downloaded? I am sure this will happen again, and I don’t think restoring your iPad is the intended user experience by Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid no such log or history exist.

Apparently either restoring a device, as iTunes does not make a backUp of your sample books, or upgrading to the lastest version of iBooks, will make your samples to dissappear.

Comment: Thanks. It’s weird how iBook still remembers the collections the books are in, and the last-read position, though.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to recover the list of all books in iBooks, including sample chapters, with the following steps:

- Select a tool to parse iPhone/iPad backups on your hard drive. Google for "iphone backup extractor", there are various.
- Select a recent iPhone/iPad backup from the list presented by your extractor software.
- Select iBooks as the app you wish to extract.
- Search for a file called `iBooks_v10252011_2152.sqlite`, or something like that.
- Use a SQLite viewer (such as Base on the Mac) to view the `ZBKBOOKINFO` table.
- Look for the `ZBOOKTITLE` field - this should contain a list of all your books, including sample chapters, from the time of the backup!
- If you want to get fancy, try sorting on the `ZSAMPLECONTENT` field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joshua C. Lerner,

Your suggestion worked. However, there are some updates in new iOS Books:

1. I used iMzing to extract backup from iTunes in MacOSX (https://imazing.com/download). It was better then 4 other software that I tested.
2. in iOS 12.3.1 iBooks is called Books
3. The list of downloaded books can be found at “BKSeries-1-012820141020.sqlite” in ZBKSERIESITEM table
4. I used Datum-Lite to open the *.sqllite files

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).   - From Review